# How to extract numbers from a String into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to put all numeric values stored in a String into an array:

```
String str = "12,1,222,55";
```

If I do this, then it will merge all numbers:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

How to get something like this?:

```
int[] result = new int[]{12,1,122,55};
```

Comment: look up string.split and Integer.parseInt in the java docs

Comment: Simply don't merge. Just split by `,` and covert element to int and store an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split the string. Then parse each element in String array to new array

```
String[] s=str.split("\\D+");
int[] intarray=new int[s.length];
for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
   intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just split your input according to one or more non-digit characters and then convert the datatype of each element to integer.

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\D+");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] numbers = str.split(",");
```

And add number one by one to `int[]` with `Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);`

If you don't know the exact size of the input string, I recommend using ArrayList for this purpose. If you know there will be 4 values then go with an array.

Answer (score 1):

Split `str` on `,` and map the elements into integers using [`Integer#parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-).

**Demo**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "12,1,222,55";

        int[] array = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
                            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                            .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
[12, 1, 222, 55]
```

### Alternatively,

Extract the integer strings using the pattern, `\d+` (i.e. one or more digits) and map them into integers using [`Integer#parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-).

```
int[] array = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                     .matcher(line)
                     .results()
                     .map(MatchResult::group)
                     .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                     .toArray();
```

**Demo**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "12,1,222,55";
        
        int[] array = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                        .matcher(str)
                        .results()
                        .map(MatchResult::group)
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
[12, 1, 222, 55]
```